# How to find memory usage by table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to discover how much memory is being used by each table. Is this information available in DMVs or elsewhere?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176018.aspx

Comment: @Hogan Brilliant!

Comment: A table is not an atomic object; all/part/parts of it may be present in the caches at any given time. What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: @Hogan hahaa no man :) I want to learn used memory by e.g "BranchOffice" Table in BANK database

Comment: @AlexK. Just want to learn used memory by all tables.Any query ?

Comment: Its not a trivial *the engine loads the table for reading*; http://stackoverflow.com/a/9230944/246342

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946957/sql-server-number-of-8k-pages-used-by-a-table-and-or-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946957/sql-server-number-of-8k-pages-used-by-a-table-and-or-database)

Answer (score 9):

what you can do is

1. Find out the database that consumes highest memory in buffer pool using below :

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cached_pages_count , 
       ( COUNT(*) * 8.0 ) / 1024 AS MB , 
       CASE database_id 
         WHEN 32767 THEN 'ResourceDb' 
         ELSE DB_NAME(database_id) 
       END AS Database_name 
   FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors 
   GROUP BY database_id
   ```
2. Drill down the database using below query :

   ```
   set nocount on;
   set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
   select
      count(*)as cached_pages_count,
      (COUNT(*) * 8.0) / 1024 AS Total_MB_Occupied, -- convert pages into MB -  the page size is 8 KB for sql server
      obj.name as objectname,
      ind.name as indexname,
      obj.index_id as indexid
   from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors as bd
   inner join
   (
       select       object_id as objectid,
                          object_name(object_id) as name,
                          index_id,allocation_unit_id
       from sys.allocation_units as au
           inner join sys.partitions as p
               on au.container_id = p.hobt_id
                   and (au.type = 1 or au.type = 3)
       union all
       select       object_id as objectid,
                          object_name(object_id) as name,
                          index_id,allocation_unit_id
       from sys.allocation_units as au
           inner join sys.partitions as p
               on au.container_id = p.partition_id
                   and au.type = 2
   ) as obj
       on bd.allocation_unit_id = obj.allocation_unit_id
   left outer join sys.indexes ind 
   on  obj.objectid = ind.object_id
   and  obj.index_id = ind.index_id
   where bd.database_id = db_id()
   and bd.page_type in ('data_page', 'index_page')
   group by obj.name, ind.name, obj.index_id
   order by cached_pages_count desc
   ```

Reference :

- [A quick look at: sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/a-quick-look-at-sys-dm_os_buffer_descriptors/)
- [What's swimming in your bufferpool?](https://web.archive.org/web/20160229195711/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/18/bufferpooldatapagesbreakdown.aspx)
- [sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors aggregations](https://web.archive.org/web/20140520095044/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chadboyd/archive/2007/02/02/sys-dm-os-buffer-descriptors-aggregations.aspx) -- more detailed info - what objects/structures/files/etc. are consuming the largest amount of space at a given time (or over time) within the Sql Server buffer pool.

Answer (score 1):

From [my tip here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2393/determine-sql-server-memory-use-by-database-and-object/):

```
;WITH src AS
(
   SELECT
       [Object] = o.name,
       [Type] = o.type_desc,
       [Index] = COALESCE(i.name, ''),
       [Index_Type] = i.type_desc,
       p.[object_id],
       p.index_id,
       au.allocation_unit_id
   FROM sys.partitions AS p
   INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS au
       ON p.hobt_id = au.container_id
   INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
       ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
   INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
       ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
       AND p.index_id = i.index_id
   WHERE au.[type] IN (1,2,3) AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
)
SELECT
   src.[Object],
   src.[Type],
   src.[Index],
   src.Index_Type,
   buffer_pages = COUNT_BIG(b.page_id),
   buffer_mb = COUNT_BIG(b.page_id) / 128
FROM src
INNER JOIN
   sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors AS b
   ON src.allocation_unit_id = b.allocation_unit_id
WHERE b.database_id = DB_ID()
GROUP BY
   src.[Object],
   src.[Type],
   src.[Index],
   src.Index_Type
ORDER BY
   buffer_pages DESC;
```